# When to use internal function and when not to?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, code-readability

I am using more and more javascript in my work and wonders what is good practice when it comes to the examples below.

```
function foo(){
    //do stuf
    var bar = foo2();
    //do stuf

    function foo2(){
        //do stuf
        return aValue;
    }
}
```

No other functions needs to know about `foo2()` which is why I sometimes hides it in `foo()`. The downside is that I think that readability of `foo()` is lost and it could be harder to locate `foo2()`. Is this good practice or should I rather do it like this:

```
function foo(){
    //do stuf
    var bar = foo2();
    //do stuf
}
function foo2(){
    //do stuf
    return aValue;
}
```

Comment: With modern JavaScript engines, this is basically a matter of preference, coding style, etc. There is no "correct" answer. There are technical advantages and disadvantages, but the choice on those trade-offs is up to you and probably varies on a case-by-case basis.